# Select Last non null-able item per product?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-5.0

Let's say I have,

```
class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Order {get; set;}
}
```

and my data have,

```
products[0] = new Product { Id = 1, Name = "P1", Order = 1 }; 
products[1] = new Product { Id = 1, Name = "P2", Order = 2 }; 
products[2] = new Product { Id = 1, Name = null, Order = 3 }; 
products[3] = new Product { Id = 2, Name = "P3", Order = 4 }; 
products[4] = new Product { Id = 2, Name = null, Order = 5 }; 
products[5] = new Product { Id = 2, Name = null, Order = 6 };
```

What I need is the last(order by Order desc) non-nullable value of Name per Product.Id. So my final output will look like,

```
items[0] =  new { Id = 1, Name = "P2"}; 
items[1] =  new { Id = 2, Name = "P3"};
```

If `Id=1`, I have 3 Names (`P1`, `P2`, `null`) and non-nullable Names (`P1`, `P2`) but last one is `P3`.

Comment: What do you mean with *last*. Do you mean the last one per `Id`?

Comment: CommuSoft, yes last one per Id. BrokenGlass I am trying as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get the last products in order.

```
var lastOrders = products
        .Where(x => x.Name != null) // Remove inapplicable data
        .OrderBy(x => x.Order) // Order by the Order
        .GroupBy(x => x.Id) // Group the sorted Products
        .Select(x => x.Last()); // Get the last products in the groups
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = products
              .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
              .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Order).Last(x => x.Name != null));
```

Answer (score 1):

this will give you your desired output:

```
products.GroupBy(p => p.Id)
        .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(gg => gg.Name)
                      .Where(gg => gg.Name != null)
                      .Select(gg => new { gg.Id, gg.Name })
                      .First());
```

Answer (score 0):

The task can be solved using the following Linq statement.

```
var Result = products.OrderBy().Where( null != iProduct.Name ).First();
```

This requires `products` to contain at least one item where `Name` is `null`, otherwise an `Exception` will be thrown. Alternatively,

```
var Result = products.OrderBy().Where( null != iProduct.Name ).FirstOrDefault();
```

will return `null` if `products` contains no such item.

Comment: I mean per Id see my expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
var expectedProduct =products.Where(p => p.Id != null).OrderByDescending(p => p.Order).GroupBy(p => p.Id).Last()
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?